# Firestore rule - limit data size

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would like to limit the data size of records added using rules. For some collections I can just use:

```
request.resource.data.values().join('').size() < 300;
```

But if a document contains a timestamp field this doesn't work. So I have to check the size() of each individual field which is a bit messy.

I could not find a way to filter out certain fields before doing the join(''). Is there a (better) way to check the size of a complete document in a rule?

-- edit --

Comment "what you mean" and "what you're doing on the client":

I would like to get a grip on the amount of data added (mainly to avoid malicious mis-use). As far as I know Firestore doesn't have some sort of throttle setting for this. Working with trigger functions and a time mechanism was an option. But for my case it doesn't have to be very accurate so I opted for a barrier by means of some maximum document size that can be added at a time. Due to restrictions on the number of documents that could possibly be added during a time-frame, this would at least pose some difficulty in trying to flood the DB. So for this I need a conditional rule on "create" that allows only documents of size smaller then x. And this hasn't have to be very accurate, I leave room for some extra surrounding meta content.

The most simple way would be a .join('').size() to determine the approximate size of a document. But if there is a non-string field somewhere in the document this will not work. Now I have to write out explicitly all fields. This is messy and not convenient for maintenance.

I couldn't find an easier or better way, so my question is "is there a better way maybe I didn't think of" to determine the size of an arbitrary document in a rule condition.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "if a document contains a timestamp field this doesn't work".  Can you provide more detail?  Please edit the question to show exactly what you're doing on the client, since rules are only meaningful in the context of a client request.

Comment: Also it's not clear to me what exactly you're trying to measure here.  The overall size of the document is not just going to be the concatenation of some string values.

Comment: The exact sizes for all data and metadata types are documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size

Comment: As by request I edited the question